# Type script node js - paytmchecksum undefined - generateSignature

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-firestore, payment-gateway, paytm

I am getting below error while integrating paytmchecksum.

> {"severity":"ERROR","message":"Unhandled error TypeError: Cannot read
> properties of undefined (reading 'generateSignature'

Code:

```
import {PaytmChecksum} from "paytmchecksum";

const checksum = await PaytmChecksum
      .generateSignature(JSON.stringify(paytmParams.body), stagingMerchantKey);

//This code works with below js code require statement:


const PaytmChecksum = require(
 "./../../../node_modules/paytmchecksum/PaytmChecksum.js");
```

But I need to deploy code on firebase firestore and need code in ts module format, please help.

Comment: Remove the curly braces from the import. `import PaytmChecksum from "paytmchecksum";`. This works on my end, let me know if this works on your end.

Comment: I love u man , thank you very much, this error was killing me since long, now it's worked.

Comment: Thanks Marc Anthony B
 But I stuck in next problem,


If i don't add below line in index.d.ts file

````
declare module 'paytmchecksum';
````


It fails in deploying to firebase cloud functions saying 

Could not find a declaration file for module 'paytmchecksum'

If I add below above mentioned entry, it compiles well but it fails in run time with below error:

{"severity":"ERROR","message":"Unhandled error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'generateSignature' - for PaytmChecksum

Comment: I would suggest creating another question for this issue.

Comment: sure,
here I have asked it:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74480491/unhandled-error-in-paytmchecksum-generatesignature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rather than using :
import {PaytmChecksum} from "paytmchecksum";

use below format:
import PaytmChecksum from "paytmchecksum";

it worked.
thanks Marc Anthony B